# Which fonts does the webOS browser support?

Tags: fonts, typography, webos, palm

Which fonts does webOS ship with / support in its web browser?

Specifically, which fonts can you specify in the stylesheet of a web page and successfully view on a webOS device?

I'm not looking for a list of "web-safe fonts". I'm looking for the list of fonts that the webOS's browser can render text in.

Comment: I don't know, but assuming searching the web turned up nothing I'd suggest looking through the OS using novaterm.  You should be able to find the font files somewhere within the device, likely in a standard Unix-y place.

Comment: The location to look is /usr/share/fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This list is valid for the Palm Pre, but I don't think that the font list has changed much since:

http://www.webos-internals.org/wiki/Fonts_available_on_board_the_Pre

Comment: Thanks. That article needs a little work, but is better than nothing.